# La caché de rails me almacena multitud de datos incluso horas después de borrar la base de de datos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, nginx

Tengo una aplicación rails que describo a continuación:

Entorno de desarrollo:
Windows + Ruby on rails + Puma (servidor por defecto) + Base de datos en sqlite + multiples bases de datos en Postgresql

Entorno de despliegue:
Centos (maquina virtual VM Waree) + Nginx como proxy inverso + Unicorn como server + las mismas bases de datos.

Pues bien, en el servidor, la aplicación se vuelve loca por momentos y no soy capaz de aislar el error por completo aunque deduzco que está en unicorn, pero podría estar en nginx.

El comportamiento incoherente sucede cuando elimino la base de datos sqlite y la sustituyo por una con datos nuevos (BBDB del entorno de desarrollo que se sube al server mediante SVN sustituyendo la anterior). Cuando hacemos esto si en la Base de datos SERVIDOR un usuario se llama Pepe y en mi máquina local tengo una réplica de esa base de datos llamada LOCAL en la que modifico el usuario y le pongo de nombre JUAN, al subir la BBDD LOCAL al servidor reemplazando a SERVIDOR, la aplicación web unas veces muestra que el usuario se llama pepe y otras que se llama Juan. Por ello deduzco que debe ser un problema de caché ¿Pero porque unas veces si lo muestra y otras no?

Un F5: Pepe, otro F5 Juan. Incluso borrando la base de datos sin dejar ninguna, la caché sigue recordando el nombre XXX y ya no sé que parámetros o que directivas cambiar.

Alguna idea de porqué puede estar pasando esto? A alguien le ha sucedido algo similar?

Entiendo que es problema de caché, pero no sé si debo limitarla en nginx, unicorn o el código de ruby.

He estado mirando por ahí y nginx da ciertos problemas en maquinas virtuales virtualbox, pero la configuración para corregir esto ya la realicé y no surte efecto, aunque en mi nuestro caso es VM Ware.

Se agradece cualquier ayuda que nos permita desatascarnos.

Comment: En tu caso, de partida no usaría sqlite. En general te funciona bien para cosas pequeñas en ambiente de desarrollo, pero ya corriendo tu app en un servidor, lo recomendable es que uses engines más enfocados para correr en un server como postgresql, mysql, etc.
De todas formas, ¿como aseguras que el problema es porque nginx te está cacheando? si refrescas la página ¿has revisado el log de rails en el server para verificar que efectivamente no está llegando el request? además si no has configurado caché en nginx, no tendría por qué estar haciéndolo por defecto.

Comment: Bien, migré a postgres y el problema se ha solucionado. Quedo sin saber que fallaba, pero al menos sin errores. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es testear sin cache en el entorno para producción:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

Si lo que buscas es limpiar la cache:

```
Rails.cache.clear
```

Explica sino con mas detalle lo que quieres buscar.

Comment: Esto ya lo he hecho, es de lo primero que probé pero no es efectivo. 
Lo que busco es que si elimino la base de datos y la sustituyo por otra, o bien si cambio cosas, no me aparezcan lecturas incorrectas de datos anteriores. Actualmente varían los valores cada vez que actualizo.

Comment: Por ejemplo, si en la Base de datos SERVIDOR un usuario se llama Pepe y en mi máquina local tengo una réplica de esa base de datos llamada LOCAL en la que modifico el usuario y le pongo de nombre JUAN, al subir la BBDD LOCAL al servidor reemplazando a SERVIDOR, la aplicación web unas veces muestra que el usuario se llama pepe y otras que se llama Juan. Por ello deduzco que debe ser un problema de caché ¿Pero porque unas veces si lo muestra y otras no?

Comment: Incluso borrando la base de datos, se acuerda de que el nombre era Pepe. Y eso que ni existe la tabla! Me estoy volviendo loco, y lo que es peor, no controlo nginx ni unicorn demasiado bien aun y no sé como aislar el problema.

Comment: Te entendí pero pense que sería tema de la cache de rails, igualmente, si tu haces una sentencia a pelo pidiendo el nombre de un cliente en concreto, cada vez que actualizas te recoge un valor diferente? (uno de la base de datos LOCAL que has borrado y otra de la base de datos SERVIDOR nueva?

Comment: Así es. De hecho, en este caso y ya hablando sobre datos reales, tengo almacenados proyectos con actividades, tareas etc y recuerda todo aun sin base de datos. Eso si, lo que recuerda es el dato de la BBDD SERVIDOR, y de vez en cuando lee el dato nuevo de la BBDD LOCAL recién subida. 

Al borrar la base de datos, puntualmente se da cuenta de que no existe la tabla user y no deja acceder a la App, pero actualizando con insistencia vuelve a encontrarla y tiene toda la información de un proyecto determinado.

Comment: No puedo ayudarte la verdad, es un problema bastante curioso, sería interesante que lo postearas en SOen que seguro que pueden ayudarte mucho mejor.

Comment: Si no consigo arreglarlo hoy, haré lo que dices. Muchas gracias por tu atención :)